# How to print path and key values of JSON file with jq

Tags: json, jq

I have a JSON with a lot of nested properties. Something like this:

```
{
  "user": {
    "name": "Matias",
    "age": 12,
  },
  "role": {
    "it": {
      "developer": true,
      "designer": false
    }
  }
}
```

And so on. I am trying to create a list of this json with each property in a single line with its "path" separated with dots. Something like this:

```
.user.name = "Matias"
.user.age = 12
.role.it.developer = true
.role.it.designer = false
```

I know I can use ".." and "to_entries" to recursively go through the object and to convert each node to key/value, but I can not figure out how to combine them in a way where the output is exactly what I want.

Comment: This [unix.so question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/561460/how-to-print-path-and-key-values-of-json-file) might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `--stream` option to produce a stream of path-value arrays. Filter for those where a value is present, `join` the path (the `first` item), and add the value (the `last` item). I used `@json` for the encoding (quotes around strings) as you didn't specify otherwise.

```bash
jq -r --stream 'select(has(1)) | ".\(first | join(".")) = \(last | @json)"'
```

```
.user.name = "Matias"
.user.age = 12
.role.it.developer = true
.role.it.designer = false
```

Note: you didn't specify what should happen with array items. This will simply use their indices instead of field names.

Comment: This is "perfecto". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the leaf nodes, and emit the path and value for each node ([demo](https://jqplay.org/s/xMzRtwmwkbE)):

```
paths(scalars | true) as $p | "\("." + ($p | join("."))) = \(getpath($p) | @json)"
```